# cannot understand why MacBook keep waking up from sleep randomly

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Macbook pro 2020 (m1) with latest macOS (12.5) seems to wake every hour or so

I have looked at the sleep log with

`pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "`

with this below result yet dont know how to decipher this

```
2022-09-05 21:04:07 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=88349':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 130 secs
2022-09-05 21:06:17 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 184 secs
2022-09-05 21:09:21 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=88439':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 305 secs
2022-09-05 21:14:26 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 17 secs
2022-09-05 21:14:43 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Software Sleep pid=88469':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-05 21:15:11 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=88469':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 305 secs
2022-09-05 21:20:16 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%) 26 secs
2022-09-05 21:20:42 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Software Sleep pid=88520':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-05 21:21:01 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=88520':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 305 secs
2022-09-05 21:26:06 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-05 21:28:01 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 826 secs
2022-09-05 21:41:47 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-06 20:24:43 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=25690':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-06 20:29:49 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-06 22:43:26 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=31915':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 850 secs
2022-09-06 23:00:36 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 807 secs
2022-09-06 23:14:48 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 128 secs
2022-09-07 07:14:47 +0300 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-07 15:11:53 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 248 secs
2022-09-07 15:16:01 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 smc.71060000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-07 17:11:21 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 830 secs
2022-09-07 17:25:11 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt bluetooth-pcie/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-07 19:56:04 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=23997':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 244 secs
2022-09-07 20:00:08 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-08 20:00:23 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=67846':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 47 secs
2022-09-08 20:01:10 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-09 09:34:31 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:100%) 263 secs
2022-09-09 09:39:39 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:100%) 828 secs
2022-09-09 09:54:13 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:100%) 178 secs
2022-09-09 09:57:12 +0300 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to Notification Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-09 10:21:21 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:100%) 48 secs
2022-09-09 10:22:55 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:100%) 130 secs
2022-09-09 10:25:36 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:100%) 3731 secs
2022-09-09 11:28:32 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:100%) 1828 secs
2022-09-09 11:59:40 +0300 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to Notification Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-09 17:47:07 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 238 secs
2022-09-09 17:51:05 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%) 96 secs
2022-09-09 17:52:41 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 623 secs
2022-09-09 18:03:04 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt bluetooth-pcie/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-09 20:22:02 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=2351':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 891 secs
2022-09-09 20:36:53 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt bluetooth-pcie/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 20 secs
2022-09-09 20:37:13 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Software Sleep pid=2477':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-09 20:37:43 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Software Sleep pid=2477':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 700 secs
2022-09-09 20:49:23 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-09 22:11:35 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 213 secs
2022-09-09 22:15:08 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 99 secs
2022-09-09 22:16:47 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 357 secs
2022-09-09 22:22:44 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 102 secs
2022-09-09 22:24:26 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 214 secs
2022-09-09 22:28:00 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-09 22:29:40 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 100 secs
2022-09-09 22:31:20 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 89 secs
2022-09-09 22:32:49 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 464 secs
2022-09-09 22:40:33 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 135 secs
2022-09-09 22:42:48 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 228 secs
2022-09-09 22:46:36 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 00:24:58 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 14 secs
2022-09-10 00:25:12 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 86 secs
2022-09-10 00:26:38 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 1028 secs
2022-09-10 00:43:46 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 102 secs
2022-09-10 00:45:28 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 41 secs
2022-09-10 00:46:09 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 112 secs
2022-09-10 00:48:01 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 471 secs
2022-09-10 00:55:52 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 92 secs
2022-09-10 00:57:24 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 956 secs
2022-09-10 01:13:20 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 02:32:03 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 902 secs
2022-09-10 02:47:05 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 02:48:43 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 523 secs
2022-09-10 02:57:26 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 88 secs
2022-09-10 02:58:54 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 701 secs
2022-09-10 03:10:35 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 04:15:00 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 307 secs
2022-09-10 04:20:07 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 05:12:01 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 20 secs
2022-09-10 05:12:21 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 95 secs
2022-09-10 05:13:56 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 947 secs
2022-09-10 05:29:43 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 06:36:08 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 219 secs
2022-09-10 06:39:47 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 06:41:25 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 13 secs
2022-09-10 06:41:38 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
2022-09-10 06:43:28 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 364 secs
2022-09-10 06:49:32 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan DataFrame ARPT/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%) 107 secs
```

can anyone help me understand what's causing this?

Comment: anyone? cant seem to solve this